# Large Memory Leak Using Reachability

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, reachability

Using Instruments on the device it detects a 3.50 KB memory leak using Apple's Reachability 2.0 code in my app. The Leaked Object is GeneralBlock-3584. The leaks tool points to the following code:

```
- (BOOL) startNotifer
{
    BOOL retVal = NO;
    SCNetworkReachabilityContext    context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    if(SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context))
    {
        // THIS IS LINE OF CODE WHERE THE LEAK OCCURS:
        if(SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachabilityRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode))
        {
            retVal = YES;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

I'm pretty much using the Reachability example straight from the Apple example code so I can't figure out why this is happening or how I fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GeneralBlock-3584` leaks are, according to official Apple statements on the developer forums (check http://devforums.apple.com, and mind your NDAs), *not a real leak* and in fact a bug in Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your Reachability object with NSAutoReleasePool. If it still exist try narrowing done towards the Leak with the autoreleasepool.

Comment: Why? Unless you have forked your own thread, there is a NSAutoReleasePool around. Wrapping it would not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar problem to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439137/cfnetwork-nsurlconnection-leak) .
Actually it seems that its a Bug within CFNetwork and it depends on the OS, 
so there is no workaround. Apple has to fix it.