# Why should I prefer ASIHTTPRequest over NSURLConnection for downloading files from the web?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

I've seen a couple of times people using ASIHTTPRequest to download files. Now I wonder why? What are the core benefits over NSURLConnection?

Comment: A year after this question, one should note that nowadays you should select AFNetworking instead of ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are several reasons. In my mind these are the major ones:

1. `ASIHTTPRequest` allows to specify a delegate for each request (vs. one delegate for a whole `NSURLConnection`); this is useful because each request has in principle a different processing once you get the data you were waiting for;
2. `ASIHTTPRequest` supports a caching mechanism that make very easy to make your app working when offline (and showing the cached data); no such mechanism in NSURLRequest;
3. If you search stackoverflow, you will find many hints at a very [strange memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439137/cfnetwork-nsurlconnection-leak) that `NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest` provoke; this is not experienced with `ASIHTTRequest`;
4. `ASIHTTRequest` offers a better implementation of Reachability, which is absolutely necessary; the Apple provided one is [said to be buggy](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/05/01/code-reachability/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Reachability implementation and the leak issues of NSURLConnection/NSURLeRquest

Comment: Sounds good. Very good. But what if Apple fixes the reachability detection bug - will ASIHTTPRequest stop working properly then?

Comment: @Mikhalo Ivanokov: no, because ASI Reachability is just a source file, no dependencies on Apple Reachability.

Comment: @sergio :- my app works fine for small pdfs when downloaded but it crashes when the pdf size is more than 2 MB. i have used NSURLConnection. Can u help me plz...

Comment: @mAc: I suspect that you are doing something incorrectly when receiving the data in the delegate. Anyway, I would suggest creating a specific question here on S.O., providing the relevant code, and you will find plenty of help...

Comment: ok i am adding a question and will provide u a link. will it be fine fr you... it will take 2 mins

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123294/my-app-crashes-when-downloading-large-pdfs-2mb-in-iphone ------ check this Que.

Answer (score 4):

`ASIHTTPRequest` is just significantly easier to use. You don't have to concatenate data blocks manually, POST requests are easy to construct, blocks are supported, `ASIHTTPRequest` is a subclass of `NSOperation` so you can easily queue up your requests, etc.

Comment: my app works fine for small pdfs when downloaded but it crashes when the pdf size is more than 2 MB. i have used NSURLConnection. Can u help me plz...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123294/my-app-crashes-when-downloading-large-pdfs-2mb-in-iphone ------ check this Que.

Answer (score 4):

ASIHTTPRequest's strength points are IMHO:

- easy to use
- file posting
- built-in authentication
- built-in zlib compression
- queing

Comment: NSURLRequest has built in zlib compression

Comment: my app works fine for small pdfs when downloaded but it crashes when the pdf size is more than 2 MB. i have used NSURLConnection. Can anyone help me plz...

Comment: @mac you should really not hijack an answer with a new question hidden as a comment -> please post a new question on SO.

Comment: Sry i have posted the question in the next answer of this Ques., u can go directly here : stackoverflow.com/questions/8123294/… ------ check this Que.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it comes down to ease of use for the programmer. It's very easy to work with and is incredibly well documented. You can very easily use queues and manage their status via delegation.

Outside the scope of files it is must easier to handle response delegation using ASI compared to the built in NSURL classes.