# Cancelable loading in background thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, thread-safety

I have a window that displays some data in an `NSTableView`. This data is loaded in the background. The data-loading-thread is started in the `windowDidLoad:` method. If the window is closed before loading has finished, the background thread should be cancelled. I do this by signalling the thread in the `windowWillClose:` delegate method and waiting for the background thread to finish.

Now this all works perfectly. But I have one problem: How can I update the data in the table view? I have tried calling `reloadData` via `performSelectorOnMainThread:` but this leads to a race condition: The `reloadData` call is sometimes queued on the main thread after the window close command, and will execute after the window has closed, and everything goes up in flames.

What's the best way to control and communicate with a background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you know, this is exactly what makes the use of threading complex: you always face synchronization issues.

What I suggest is, instead of calling `[tableView reloadData]` from your thread, simply signal your controller (by calling a method `controllerShouldReloadTable`) and let your controller do the check if `windowWillClose` has been called or not. There might be a chance that your controller has been also released by the time `controllerShouldReloadTable`, and to fix this you will definitely need to `retain` the controller from the secondary thread.

On a side note, I would cancel the thread in `viewDidUnload` (for symmetry).

Most important: I would use asynchronous calls and a delegate class so that the whole multithreading issue is solved at its root.

EDIT: Sending asynchronously a request will not block the sending thread waiting for the response. Instead, asynchronous send (for `NSURLConnection` is called `start`) immediately returns (so, no blocking) and when the response is received, a delegate method will be called (i.e., `connectionDidFinishLoading:`) so that you can updated the model and the UI. Take a look at [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs, but as usual, I strongly suggest using `[ASIHTTPRequest][2]`, which has [many advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143188/why-should-i-prefer-asihttprequest-over-nsurlconnection-for-downloading-files-fro/6143324#6143324).

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll try this. But I can't use `viewDidUnload` because that's only available on iOS, and in Cocoa a window is not a view. I don't think I need to retain the controller because the `performSelector` methods retain the target anyway. Could you elaborate on what you mean with "asynchronous calls and delegate classes"? I'm not sure I understand this.

Comment: I tried it, and it seems to work now. If threaded programming only wasn't so hard...

Comment: Jakob, see my edit.. you will love async I/O, it is so natural to event-loop based systems...

Comment: Oh, thanks! Now I understand. I'm not sure if this will help me in my case, as I'm not loading data from HTTP, but rather from a database using my own classes, which don't have this async-type interface.