# My app crashes when downloading large pdfs (>2MB) in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest

My app is working fine for downloading small Pdf's and showing them in WebView but when i fetch url of pdfs having size more than 2 MB it crashes everytime.

Code :-

```
@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize scrollView,receivedData,myIndicator;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

{   
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [myIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [myIndicator startAnimating];

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_landscape.png"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;
    [background release];   

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://litofinter.es.milfoil.arvixe.com/displayxml1.aspx"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:150.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    int x=10,y=50;

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45,320, 480)];   
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,5000);
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

    for (Litofinter *lito in appDelegate.bookArray) {
        if([appDelegate.currentButtonPressed isEqualToString:lito.cName])
        {
            NSLog(@"Count == %d ===",[lito.productsArray count]);
            for (Products *prod in lito.productsArray) {

                NSString * urlString = [prod.thumbnail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

                NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                [myIndicator stopAnimating];
                [myIndicator removeFromSuperview];

                UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];
                [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 190)];
                [imageButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageButton setTitle:prod.pdf forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapBook:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];

                x = x + 160;

                if(x >300)
                {
                    y = y +250;
                    x = 10;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];


}

-(void)onTapBook:(id)sender{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    appDelegate.currentBookPressed = [button currentTitle];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Ver Catalogo!" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:@"Ver on-line",@"Descargar",nil];
    [alert show];
}

// when I click on Descargar button i.e. download it goes to next PdfShowViewController

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
{  

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];  

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Ver on-line"])  
    { 
        viewController2 = [[PdfShowViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PdfShowViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];

    }  

    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Descargar"])  
    {       
        viewController2 = [[PdfShowViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PdfShowViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
    }  

} 


-(IBAction)onTapBack{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [scrollView release];
}


@end

// here i am showing the pdf on a webView and downloading them

@implementation PdfShowViewController

@synthesize pdfWebview,myIndicator,progress,receivedData,DownloadRequest,DownloadConnection,downloadLabel,openURL;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];

    unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
    [receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];
    NSLog(@"Data === %ld",receivedData);

    NSInteger receivedLen = [data length];
    bytesReceived = (bytesReceived + receivedLen);
    NSLog(@"received Bytes ==  %f",bytesReceived);

    if(expectedBytes != NSURLResponseUnknownLength) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Expected Bytes in if ==  %f",expectedBytes);
        NSLog(@"received Bytes in if ==  %f",bytesReceived);

        float value = ((float) (bytesReceived *100/expectedBytes))/100;
        NSLog(@"Value ==  %f",value);
        progress.progress=value;
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"%f",expectedBytes);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [myIndicator stopAnimating];
    [myIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [progress setHidden:YES];
    [downloadLabel setHidden:YES];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MayankPdf.pdf"];

    unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
    [receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];

    [self.receivedData  writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

    [connection release];

    //Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [pdfWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [pdfWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [downloadLabel setText:@"Downloading..."];
    [downloadLabel setHidden:NO];

    [myIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [myIndicator startAnimating];

    NSLog(@"REquired --------------------------------%@",appDelegate.currentBookPressed);
    //  NSString *urlString = [appDelegate.currentBookPressed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *urlString = [appDelegate.currentBookPressed stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"The Url Stirng=======%@",urlString);

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"Trageted String ------======++++++++%@",targetURL);
    DownloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:120.0];
    DownloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:DownloadRequest delegate:self];

    if (DownloadConnection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];
    }

    [pdfWebview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    //  [pdfWebview loadRequest:DownloadRequest];


}

-(IBAction)onTapBack
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [pdfWebview release];
    //  [receivedData release];
}


@end
```

**My parser also not accepting URLS having space, any solutions will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance**

Pardon me if have written something wrong as i am not very good in Iphone.

Comment: Post your crash log here. "My App Crashes" is vague, provide as much debugging info you can when asking a question.

Comment: Actually on machine it is not crashing but when run on device it is crashing... sorry to ask how can i give debugging log in this condition, i think connecting device and then running in debugging mode will give me the log errors??

Comment: right, if you connect the device and run the app from xcode, you will see the log...

Comment: dude sry my iphone is having IOS 5 and i am developing on XCode 3.2 because of some reason. so can not give debugging details.By the way a previous version of my app LITOFINTER is on Appstore (Free) having same code for downloading PDF's and soon i will update this version also on Appstore.so i vl try my best to provide u the error log ASAP. By the way have i written anything wrong for downloading PDF, means other then memry problem what it can be??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably exceeding the 30MB RAM limit,

you shouldn't use a NSMutableData object to reconstruct the full file but write it directly on "disk" to limit memory usage.

to inspire you

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    @synchronized(connection) {
        m_downloadedBytes += [data length];
        CGFloat downloadProgress = ((CGFloat) m_downloadedBytes / (CGFloat) m_fileSize);
        [self setDownloadProgress:downloadProgress];        

        if (!m_fileHandle) {
            [data writeToURL:m_tmpTargetURL atomically:NO];
            m_fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingToURL:m_tmpTargetURL error:NULL] retain];
            [m_fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        }
        else {
            [m_fileHandle writeData:data];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for a descriptive answer.it was a very long back Question btw :), i changed the method at all to achieve the target. But thanks for your Interest.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say in your comment (app crashing on the device but not on the simulator) and taking into account that you are downloading large PDF files, my guess is that you are running into memory problems and your app is killed by the system (this is usually associated with a log message about a signal 0 being sent to the app).

If this is true, I would suggest that you store the data you download incrementally; i.e., you don't append all the data in `NSData` and at the very end (when you got all data) you store them to a file. You can append to a file each received chunk and free your memory.

On the other hand, I don't understand very well why you are doing this:

```
unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
[receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];
```

since you are not using `byteBuffer` elsewhere in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method. This is not the cause of the issue, I think, since the local variable is deallocated thereafter, but still if you receive a big chunk of data you are duplicating it (once in NSData, a second time on the stack).

About the space problem in your URLs, you should think of escaping them by using

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
```

which is a `NSString` method.

Comment: no.. :( i am not running out of memory. and regarding that:----        unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
[receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];         ---- i was doing this to get all the data in NSMutableData Object.(sry if i have done it wrong),i will be posting the log errors in few mins, can u correct my code if possible or tell me what should i do. :)

Answer (score 1):

First most of thing you alloc is not released(theconnection,alert,viewcontroller2)

second `[connection release];` in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` which connection you are releasing

after clearing this issue check and run the app. then explain what is your exception or error.